# Possible to get a closed form expression, or an upper bound, for $ f(n)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{m+n}{3}\bigg)^{m+n}\bigg(\frac{1}{m}\bigg)^m$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

Is it possible to get a closed form expression, or an upper bound, for the following function $f$ which is given by an infinite summation:

$$
f(n) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{m+n}{3}\bigg)^{m+n} \bigg(\frac{1}{m}\bigg)^m,
$$
for $n > 0$? Also, $n$ can be assumed to be large if this is any help.

Note when $n=0$, it is simply
$$
f(0) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: It looks like a some sort of factorial when graphed and the sum looks similar to a binomial series.

Comment: Is there anything that suggests the function has a closed form?

Comment: Nothing beyond the fact that its terms are relatively simple. An upper bound on the function would also be enough I think.

Comment: I see. Personally I don't actually think it's that simple and there are simpler series (e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{x}}{i^{i}}$) that don't have closed forms. You can possibly get a nice asymptotic for your series though.

Comment: In fact, from looking at the graphs, I think $\ln f(x)\sim 0.817x\ln\left(x\right)$ or $\sim x\ln x- x$.

Comment: Yes, that does indeed seem pretty close, the 0.817 coefficient is a bit arbitrary however.

Comment: The $x\ln x -x$ seems to be a good bit off. In general I want a closed-form, approximation, or bound that can be justified.

Comment: The function growth is at least exponential. 

$$f(n) \geq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{m}{3}\right)^{m+n}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^m = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^m}\left(\frac{m}{3}\right)^n > \frac{1}{3^4}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^n.$$

Comment: @JoshuaZ Yes it grows very rapidly. I’m currently looking at splitting the summation at a large N and seeing if I can get an upper bound that way.

Comment: Using Stirling formula we have a problem with small values of $m$ . But how is the approximation $~\displaystyle f(n)\approx n!\left(\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^n - \left(\frac{e}{3}\right)^n\right)~$ for you ? Especially for small or large $n$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can derive bounds and approximations for $f(n)$ that suggest properties that such a closed form must have.

$$f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{n+i}{3}\right)^{n+i}}{i^i}
$$

When $n$ is fixed, the summands, $a_i$, are increasing over $(0,\frac{n}{2})$ but decreasing over $(\frac{n}{2},\infty)$. This can be shown by considering their derivatives. By bounding the summand with continuous curves and accounting for the peak at $n/2$, we can deduce that

$$f(n)\leq\int_{1/2}^{n/2-1/2}a_{i+1/2}\,\mathrm{d}i+ a_{n/2}+\int_{n/2+1/2}^{\infty}a_{i-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}i$$

Then, by substitution with $i\mapsto i\pm1/2$, $$f(n)\leq\int_{1}^{\infty}a_{i}\,\mathrm{d}i+ a_{n/2}$$

Rearranging $a_i$ to $\left(\frac{n+i}{3}\right)^{n}\cdot e^{-i\ln\left(\frac{3}{\frac{n}{i}+1}\right)}$ allows us to bound it by incorporating the inequality $1-\frac1x\leq \ln x \leq x-1$. Hence,

$$\left(\frac{n+i}{3}\right)^{n}\cdot e^{\frac{i\left(n-2i\right)}{n+i}}\leq a_i\leq \left(\frac{n+i}{3}\right)^{n}\cdot e^{\frac{n}{3}-\frac{2}{3}i}$$

Combining this upper bound with the previous integral inequality,

$$\begin{aligned}f(n)&\leq\frac{e^{\frac{n}{3}}}{3^{n}}\int_{1 }^{\infty }\frac{\left(n+i\right)^{n}}{e^{\frac{2}{3}i}}\,\mathrm{d}i+ \left(\frac{n}2\right)^{n}
\\
&\leq \frac{3e^{n}}{2^{n+1}}\Gamma\left(n+1,\frac{2\left(n+1\right)}{3}\right)+ \left(\frac{n}2\right)^{n}\end{aligned}$$

where $\Gamma(s,x)=\int_1^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t$ is the incomplete gamma function. When $x\gg 0$, we have $\Gamma(s,x)\approx x^{s-1}e^{-x}$. Hence, for large $n$, $$f(n)\approx \frac{3}{2e^{\frac{2}{3}}}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{1}{3}}}{3}\left(n+1\right)\right)^{n}+\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{n}$$

---

#### Update 2019-11-05. Improved bounds.

Expanding on **@user90369's** ingenious use of Stirling's approximation to bound $n^n$, we can use the existing upper and lower bounds for $n!$ to sandwich $n^n$. We can then choose the relevant bounds for the numerator and denominator of the summands of $f(n)$ to find the improved bounds

$$\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}e^{n}}{3^{n}e}\leq \frac{f(n)}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(n+i\right)!\sqrt{\frac{i}{n+i}}}{3^{n}\cdot i!}} \leq \frac{e^{n+1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}3^{n}}
\\
\\
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e\sqrt{n+1}}
\leq
\frac{f(n)}{\frac{e^{n}}{3^{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(n+i\right)!}{3^{i}\cdot i!}}
 \leq \frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\\
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e\sqrt{n+1}}
\leq
\frac{f(n)}{e^{n}n!\left(\frac{3}{2}\cdot2^{-n}-3^{-n}\right)}
 \leq \frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

So - unless I'm mistaken, since I'm not great with asymptotic analysis - this means that $f(n)\in\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}2\right)^n\right)$ and $f(n)\in\mathcal{\Omega}\left(\left(\frac{n}2\right)^n\right)$. This lends itself to the natural approximation $f(n)\approx k\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$ or $f(n)\approx k\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$, the best of which seems to be the good approximation

$$f(n)\approx 2.172\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$$

Comment: By using Stirling's approximation twice and using the approximation $\frac{\sqrt{i}}{\sqrt{n+i}}\approx \frac{\sqrt{i}}{\sqrt{n}}$ when $n$ is large and then assuming $\sqrt{i}\ll (n+i)!, i!, 3^i$, we have $f(n)\approx \frac{e^{n}n!}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{3}{2}2^{-n}-3^{-n}\right)$.

Comment: Very nice approximation and its great to see the techniques used in case I come across similar situations in future..thanks!

Comment: Footnote: I think the $2.172\ldots$ constant is $\frac{\sqrt{6\pi}}{2}$, which would fit given the relation to Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Footnote 2: I believe that this can be generalised to $\frac{1}{a^{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(n+i\right)^{n+i}}{\left(ai\right)^{i}}\sim \frac{\sqrt{2a\pi n}}{a-1}\left(\frac{n}{a-1}\right)^{n}$.

Answer (score 5):

*Only a comment.*

I am not sure if you will like this, because my commentary shows that it's *unlikely* that you will get a satisfying answer in relation to a *closed form* .

$$\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\left(\frac{m+n}{3}\right)^{m+n}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^m = \frac{1}{3^n}\sum\limits_{v=0}^\infty{\binom n v}n^{n-v}\left(\frac{d^{v+1}}{dx^{v+1}}\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{h(e^{\frac{t}{3}e^{x-t}})^n}{1-\ln h(e^{\frac{t}{3}e^{x-t}})}dt\right)\big{|}_{x=0}$$

$h(x)~$ is the *infinite* [power tower](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) . $\,$It's useful if $~n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ .

*Conclusion:* Lower bound and an upper bound make sense, especially an asymptotic formula.

I think the upper bound $~\displaystyle n!\left(\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{e}{3}\right)^n\right)~$ for $~f(n)~$ could be a good start for looking for a better one.

Comment: Please explain how this suggests that a closed form is unlikely.

Comment: @Jam : Because of the integral, of course. And there is no need for downvotes, it's only a  *comment*, a base for considerations, not a claim, not a proof.

Comment: Interesting answer thanks! I have derived an upper bound now..it gives the rate of convergence which is sufficient for what I need. But I would still be interested to see if a closed form is possible or an ‘almost closed form’ if not.

Comment: @user90369 That upper bound is very nice, I would be interested to see how you derived it.

Comment: @eurocoder : You've accepted the other answer, so I think you've tested that it is a better approximation. That's good. But to answer your question: I only used the Stirling formula $~n!\approx (n/e)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}~$ , means: $~x^x\approx x!e^x/\sqrt{2\pi x}~$ with $~x\in\{n,m+n\}~$ .